# How to prevent Ubuntu from deactivating "Other software" repository after upgrade?

Tags: google-chrome, repository

After every Ubuntu upgrade I have to reactivate Google Chrome's repository (among others).

I'm looking for a way to prevent automatic deactivation of specific repositories.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Why? This is done to prevent the updater crashing over software Canonical has no say over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you can not restrict upgrade from disabling third party repos. you can re-enable it using the below details.

**Method 1:**

gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update

**Method 2:**

Another option is going to System > Administration > Software Sources, Other Software, then checking the boxes next to the PPAs you want to have enabled.

Comment: Yeah, I do it after every upgrade.  But I believe too there's no way to disable it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't (or shouldn't) prevent third part repositories to be disabled during upgrade.

They are disabled to ensure that they do not interfere with the update process. As part of the preparation to the upgrade note down what third part repositories you have, and after update enable them again.